# Iphone, how to add outline on an image?

Tags: iphone

I want to add outline on an image, do you have any idea? 
Note: I don't need the border of imageview, not imageview.layer.borderColor nor image.layer.borderWidth;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source;
{
    CGSize size = [source size];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0); 
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return testImg;
}
```

source : http://www.icodesnip.com/snippet/objective-c/add-image-border-to-uiimage

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, but you add a rectangle border, while what I need is the outline of the image. eg, a hat image, I need a outline around the hat, not a rectangle around it.

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: this kind of operation may need image processing, try using http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/ but it seems to be not that simple

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a very clean way but may work and is simple.

```
//Make a UIView instance with required coords and size
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];

//Set a backgroundColor, that will be the color of your border
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor ...];

// Make a UIImageView instance with the frame just leaving enough
// space around for the border.
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
imageView.image = yourImage;

// Add the imageView to the view.
[view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

// Release view accordingly after adding to some other view.
```

The sizes of the view and imageView will what give your image a border.
eg. (0, 0, 10, 10) -> view frame
    (1, 1, 8, 8)   -> imageView frame
This will give border of "1" to the image.